# GTM tag not firing - Conditions being met

Tags: performance, click, google-tag-manager

I want my GTM tag to fire for some clicks by using the elementClasses from the Object stated below. I've tried different configurations for the tag and trigger but nothing seems to work. It's not firing.

After searching for a specific drug (e.g. advil) on this site https://www1.shoppersdrugmart.ca/en/internal/rx-inventory then several options appear with the 'Check Availability' button on the far right. Once clicked it opens a pop-up window. I'm trying to track the number of clicks on that button but to no avail! 
NB I have admin access to GTM and GA360 for this account.
Would appreciate anyone's help. Banging my head against the wall!!

```
    Object
event:"gtm.click"
gtm.element:"[HTMLElement]"
gtm.elementClasses:"drug-inventory-results-table__availability-icon"
gtm.elementId:""
gtm.elementTarget:""
gtm.elementUrl:"https://www1.shoppersdrugmart.ca/static/drug-inventory/images/check-availability-button.png"
gtm.uniqueEventId:143
```

[image: GTM debug window]

[image: GTM Tag Configuration]
[image: GTM Trigger Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using matchesRegEx(ignoreCase) instead of the equals in the trigger?